# Regex to select all the commas from string that do not have any white space around them

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to select all the commas in a string that do not have any white space around. Suppose I have this string:

```
"He,she, They"
```

I want to select only the comma between `he` and `she`. I tried this in rubular and came up with this regex:

```
(,[^(,\s)(\s,)])
```

This selects the comma that I want, but also selects an `s` which is a character after it.

[image]

Comment: This is selecting the comma that has white space around it. I want to select the other one that does not have any white space around it.

Comment: That should be a positive lookahead instead `(?<=\S),(?=\S)` [demo](http://rubular.com/r/2HWhJHGKYx)

Comment: Yes, this works. Thanks.
Didn't know about lookahead and lookbehind.

Comment: Do you want to match things like `@,@` also ?

Comment: Yes, everything except for white space. Actually, I have a string that I want to add to a CSV (which has comma separation). But there are many columns that has data which contains "comma and space". So everything except for white space.

Comment: What do mean by “select commas in a string...”? Do you wish to return an array of indices of the commas that have the desired property, the number of commas having the desired property or something else?

Comment: @CarySwoveland My usecase is to split a string at all the places where a comma is present but without any white spaces around it. I am using ruby. So doing that using a regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex `(,[^(,\s)(\s,)])` you capture a comma followed by a negated character class that matches not any of the specified characters, which could also be written as `(,[^)(,\s])` which will capture for example `,s` in a group,

What you could do is use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a positve lookbehind to check what is on the left and what is on the right is not a `\S` whitespace character:

`(?<=\S),(?=\S)`

[Regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/2HWhJHGKYx)

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you may use `[[:space:]]` to match any (Unicode) whitespace and `[^[:space:]]` to match any char other than whitespace. Using these character classes inside [*lookarounds*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) solves the problem:

```
/(?<=[^[:space:]]),(?=[^[:space:]])/
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/OXEgVwaV2m)

Here,

- `(?<=[^[:space:]])` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with a non-whitespace char (if the string start position should also be matched, replace with `(?<![[:space:]])`)
- `,` - a comma
- `(?=[^[:space:]])` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a non-whitespace char (if the string end position should also be matched, replace with `(?![[:space:]])`).

Answer (score 0):

Check the regex below and use the code hope it will help you!

```
re = /[^\s](,)[^\s]/m
str = 'check ,my,domain, qwe,sd'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
puts match.to_s
end
```

Check [LIVE DEMO HERE](https://regex101.com/r/AuvzNa/1)